# Нуждаюсь в рекомендации: как комфортно перейти на более серьезный уровень разработки ПО

Tags: php, python, java, c++

Первым делом надо сказать, что я не профессиональный программист. Я занимаюсь этим как любитель. Мне просто нравится это делать.

Когда-то давно я познакомился с любительскими программами, которые позволяют освоить азы программирования. И вот, я пользуюсь ими уже много лет и никак не могу соскочить на что-то более серьезное.

Я понятия не имею какие языки программирования там используются. Я не в курсе что это за синтаксис. Я просто изучал возможности этих программ.

Итак, на данный момент я пользуюсь двумя программами: "AutoPlay Media Studio" и "Automatic Mouse and Keyboard".
Первая программа - это GUI-конструктор интерфейса, который изначально создавался для быстрого создания программ автозапуска. Но в принципе, там есть плагины, довольно широкий список команд, какой-никакой справочник, более-менее понятный синтаксис, неплохой компилятор, и т.д.

Ниже скидываю скриншот того, как эта программа выглядит в работе:
[image: AutoPlay Media Studio]

То есть, сначала я создал большой синий лист, добавил на него элементы, надписи, прогресс-бар, а затем стал писать код взаимодействия этих элементов.

Вторая программа в моем арсенале - Automatic Mouse and Keyboard - это, по сути, очень сильно прокачанный автокликер, который позволяет работать с переменными, создавать циклы, строить конструкции if/else, работать с файлами, реестром Windows, базами данных, создавать диалоговые окна, и еще очень много чего. Там тоже имеется простенький встроенный компилятор в .exe.

Вот скриншот окна этой программы:

[image: Automatic Mouse and Keyboard]

При должном количестве всевозможных костылей, этими программами можно делать очень много всяких крутых штук - этим я и развлекал себя уже лет 10, самостоятельно углубляясь в тему программирования. Без учебников, без советов более умных и опытных людей. Просто сам сидел, пробовал, и учился на практике, вот и всё.

Сейчас мне не хватает развития. Я остро почувствовал, что настало время покинуть эти ясли и наконец-то перейти на что-то более взрослое. Но я не знаю какие языки программирования мне подойдут? Хочется, чтобы переход был более-менее комфортным. Чтобы моих текущих навыков хватило хотя бы для старта!

Как вы думаете, какими программами мне было бы комфортно заменить эти две? Посоветуйте, пожалуйста. Я буду вам очень благодарен.

(ну, или хотя бы укажите на язык с похожим синтаксисом))))

Comment: Если телефон на Андроиде, скачай андроид студио и начни что-нибудь писать для себя. А там подтянется

Comment: На Ваш вопрос невозможно дать однозначный правильный ответ, они все будут основаны на мнениях, поэтому ниже исключительно моё личное мнение. Язык и инструменты выбираются исходя из задач. К сожалению синтаксис, который используется в ваших примерах, это что-то вроде VisualBasic и Pascal. Оба языка древние и обычно их предпочитают не использовать, если есть альтернатива. А так вам должен был бы зайти Delphi, который имеет примерно схожую концепцию: вот вам форма GUI, кидаете на неё элементы и прописываете им поведение.

Comment: Альтернативно можно взять .Net, он тоже поддерживает подобную концепцию, если делать WinForms приложения. Вот вам формы, вот элементы которые вы кидаете на формы и прописываете им поведение. Так можно войти во что-то более менее серьезное. Он поддерживает так же Visual Basic, но зачастую предпочитают использовать C#, в принципе меняется только синтаксис.

Comment: Посмотрите, тут есть пример создания трех приложений (в левом меню навигация), может вам и зайдет: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/ide/create-csharp-winform-visual-studio?toc=%2Fvisualstudio%2Fget-started%2Fcsharp%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fvisualstudio%2Fget-started%2Fcsharp%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=vs-2019

Comment: Большое спасибо. Пока склоняюсь к выбору .Net - выглядит относительно дружелюбно и довольно функционально. Правда, синтаксис пока пугает))) Ну, ничего. Привыкну :)

Еще раз большое спасибо.